# elections.stackexchange.com not working in IE9 (Vista x64)

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

Currently, the election page stops before it's finished loading the "completed elections" section (this works fine in Chrome and FireFox).

This is all you get right now (in IE9 on Windows Vista 64-bit):

[image]

As far as I know, there’s currently an election on SuperUser, so it should be showing up here to select.

In the console, I see this error occuring:

```
SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object  
jquery.min.js, line 26 character 449
```

Comment: I'm having the same experience ([as is Tim Stone](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=993701#993701) as of about a month ago), and I'm on IE9 on Win7.  There's a JavaScript error showing in the console: "*SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object jquery.min.js, line 26 character 449*"

Answer (score 9):

<s>For some reason the fix for this bug has been reverted on the live site. I'll figure out what happened and make sure it gets re-updated. Once that happens everything should work correctly.</s>

For some reason I've gone completely crazy and imagined that the fix for this bug had been deployed, but it never actually was. [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) was kind enough to *actually* deploy it now, so everything should be good now (you may need to F5 to refresh any cached javascript; we'll work on correcting that in an upcoming update).

The problem was a [missing comma](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-election-stats/source/detail?r=911cf19e7c04e7032cd9c5a47f5726a40f311b61) that caused a variable to be accidentally introduced into the global scope, except in IE where the variable name was shadowed by a native method.

Comment: [It's Yi Jiang's fault!](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/AYPpF/24/embedded/result/)